# Python convert a Tkinter script to an exe application

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, desktop-application

I'm designing a Tkinter app in VsCode. When I convert it into a desktop app by using the `cxfreeze` method from [py-auto-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), they raise errors:

1. `msi` file cannot install in the system
2. if install cannot show in the system
3. `.exe` file can run in my system but not in other systems: python error is raised

Answer (score 2):

You should use [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/).

Then run in cmd `pyinstaller [your main file] -D --clean` and run the exe file. It won't work if there are errors in your code.